# Как добавить блок "Поделиться" от Яндекса на сайт, сделанный на платформе Google Sites?

Tags: соцсети, google-sites

Как получить код для вставки понятно. А как разместить его на странице, сделанной с помощью `Google Sites`? Везде полно примеров для `WorldPress`, А для `Google Sites` не нашёл

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы создать нестандартный элемент сайта, вставьте HTML-поле на нужную страницу. Вы можете использовать JavaScript, HTML или CSS.

Откройте сайт в Google Сайтах.

Слева на карте сайта выберите нужную страницу.

Нажмите на значок Изменить.

Выберите область на странице.

Нажмите Вставка дальше Поле HTML.

Добавьте в него код HTML, CSS или JavaScript.

Нажмите кнопку СОХРАНИТЬ.

В правом верхнем углу выберите "Сохранить".

https://support.google.com/sites/answer/2500646?hl=ru

Там же см. Возможные причины неполадок.